# How to make one item selected at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At the default state I want 'ALL' to be selected. Click on another item will change all other classes so that 'this' has the class and the others don't. My problem is why can't 'ALL' be re-selected?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u5g9vLkx/

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav2">
    <li><a href="#" class="orange2">ALL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="orange">PERSONAL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="orange">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="orange">WORK</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background: #000000;
}
.nav2{
    float: none;
    list-style-type:none;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.nav2 li{
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 10px;  
}

.orange{
    opacity: .5;
    color: #FF9000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.orange:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    color:#000000;
    background: #FF9000;
}

.orange2{
    color: #FF9000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #FF9000; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.orange2:hover{
    color:#000000;
    background: #FF9000;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('a.orange').click(function(){
$('a.orange2').addClass('orange');
$('a.orange').removeClass('orange2');
$(this).removeClass('orange');
$(this).addClass('orange2');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Javascript code you are applying the onClick listener only to `a.orange` (`a` elements with the class `orange`)

```
$('a.orange').click(function(){ ... });
```

Since the "ALL" menu entry does not have `orange`, but `orange2` as its class, it is not affected by that.

You can fix this by including `a.orange2` in the selector:

```
$('a.orange, a.orange2').click(function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that :

```
 <ul class="nav2">
      <li><a href="#" class="orange2">ALL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="orange2">PERSONAL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="orange2">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="orange2">WORK</a></li>
 </ul>

 $('a.orange2').click(function(){
      $('a.orange2').removeClass('orange2').addClass('orange');
      $(this).addClass('orange2').removeClass('orange');
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/khzehpfx/